# Spring MVC - Bind ID to an Object using a converter (ConversionServiceFactoryBean)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have two classes (`Team`, `Coach`) :
**Team.java :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TEAM")
public class Team {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID_TEAM")
    private Long idTeam;

    @Column(name = "NAME_TEAM")
    private String nameTeam;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_COACH")
    private Coach coach;

    //Getters & Setters...
}
```

**Coach.java :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="COACH")
public class Coach {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID_COACH")
    private Long idCoach;

    @Column(name = "NAME_COACH")
    private String nameCoach;

    @OneToOne
    private Team team;

    //Getters & Setters...
}
```

As you can see, there is a `OneToOne` relationship between them.

In my form, i retrieve (successfully) all the coachs from the DB.

```
<form action="add" method="post">
    <label for="nameTeam">Team <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="nameTeam" id="nameTeam"/>

    <label for="coach">Coach <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
    <select name="coach" id="coach">
        <option value="" disabled selected>- Select a coach -</option>
        <c:forEach var="coach" items="${coachs}">
            <option value="${coach.idCoach}">${coach.nameCoach}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>

    <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

So i choose a coach from the `select` element. When i submit the form, the Team is added in the DB but i get a `null` in the `ID_COACH` field.

Here is my `Controller` :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/team/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addTeam(Team team) {
    this.teamService.add(team);
    return "new_team";
}
```

The `ConversionService` :

```
<!-- Conversion Service -->
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"/>

<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <list>
            <bean class="converters.ToCoach"/>
        </list>
    </property> 
</bean>
```

And here is my `Converter` :

```
public class ToCoach implements Converter<Long, Coach> {    
    @Autowired
    CoachRepository coachRepo;

    public Coach convert(Long idCoach) {
        return this.coachRepo.findOne(idCoach);
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyone??! I'm kind of stuck here ...

Comment: the Big Problem is I don't get any error message in the console, which makes hard (if not impossible) to solve it....

Comment: Is your converter getting invoked?

Comment: I added a "sysout" inside the convert method but nothing showed up in the console... so i think the converter is not invoked but i don't know why

Comment: Take a look at this JIRA request `https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6801`. you might have to try with `@ModelAttribute` annotation on your controller. Also note the spring version that has the fix. Let me know if it works, curious to understand if `@ModelAttribute` annotation makes the difference.

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: I got the exact same problem, have you solved it?

Comment: I got it done by using formatter